# Salesforce soap connection namespace issue

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, salesforce

- I am using a soap API to called Apex service method using Java.

  - I am already connection to salesforce org using the partner API.
  - I have prepared the WSDL for the global class where I have write the webservice method.
  - I have converted that WSDL file Jar file.
  - Now while I have added that jar file into my project and fire that event that webservice method was called.
  - It's work fine but while I have fire that event from the package org, I got an exception.

**Issue**
I know the issue, issue is namespace but, did't know how to solve it.

Here is my sample code.

```
SoapConnection globalUtilConnection = Connector.newConnection("","");
globalUtilConnection.getConfig().setAuthEndpoint(updatedServerURL.toString());
globalUtilConnection.getConfig().setServiceEndpoint(updatedServerURL.toString());
globalUtilConnection.setSessionHeader(activeSessionId);
globalUtilConnection.myWebServiceMethod();
```

**It's work fine for my developer organization But, It was causing an issue in Package org **

**Note: ** WSDL file was generated from the developer organization.

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 1):

So, you have an Apex class using the [`webservice`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm) keyword to expose a method as a SOAP web service?

When you take that Apex class from you developer edition org to the packaging org it will pick up the namespace of the packaging org. This changes the URL you need to call.

The namespace of the packaging org will appear in a few places in the WSDL.

1. In the `xmlns:tns` attribute

   > xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/**orgNamespace**/TestClass"
2. In the `targetNamespace` attribute

   > targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/**orgNamespace**/TestClass"
3. In the `soap:address` `location` attribute

   > location="https://na5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/**orgNamespace**/TestClass"

The endpoint location should be fairly easy to handle. You can just alter the endpoint URL to include the org namespace in the path.

The targetNamespace and tns alias will be harder to resolve. The easiest option might be to recreate the jar from the WSDL with the updated namespaces.

See also: [Adding Namespace to Webservice Class Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008vvdIAA)

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thanks for the quick response.
recreating jar file is good idea.
I had already tied that it is working fine in package org.
But, then after it was not working for the developer edition org.
Can we handle namespace pragmatically so that I can use that code for the developer edition org and package edition org.
In **partner api** I have used method called **setCalloption() to handle namespace.

`connection.setCallOption(clientName,namespce);`

Comment: Can I change this attributes pragmatically?

Comment: Yes I have dynamically added namespace in AuthEndpoint & ServiceEndpoint but still I got an issue.
I have also check my endpoins it was updated properly with namespcae.
something like: https://NAMESPACE.serverURL/services/Soap/class/NAMESPACE/MyClass
after update that URL I got an exception.
com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/MyClass}.

Comment: @Chintan So the jar using the WSDL from the packaging org works against that org, but not the developer edition org? That seems about right due to the namespace being in the URL and the targetNamespace of the SOAP requests. I'd try and do a comparison between the Java classes in the JAR. You could probably find what you need to toggle programatically with a diff tool.